# Flutter: Getting Connection timed out , address = 192.168.1.141, port = 54486 when trying to connect my real device with local django api

Tags: django, flutter, api, networking

I'm trying to connect my flutter app with a local rest API.It doesn't work

```
static Future<List<User>> userList(int comp) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.141:8000/api/users"),
      headers: <String,String>{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
      body: jsonEncode(<String,int>{"id_user":id_user})
    );
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      return jsonResponse.map((user) => Compteur.fromJson(user)).toList();
    }else{
      throw Exception("Error");
    }
  }
```

My laptop and the smartphone I use for the test are in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

You got an 110 status code. Connection timed out.

It is a network failure. Many things are here possible. This is not a coding failure.
You can try to debug it with wireshark.
It is possible that you have a firewall that will block your request.
Or maybe a failure in the routing table? Maybe is your router or a switch in your network defect.

If you use Windows, it's possible blocked by windows defender. Try to configure it.
If you have a *nix OS, try to scan your laptop with nmap:

```
nmap -p 8000,54486 -sV 192.168.1.141
```

If the port is closed, try to figure out, why it is closed. Most likely: there is a firewall which blocks your request.

If it is open, try to test your API from another device (instead from your mobile phone).

PS: In your title you are using port 54486. In your code, you are using port 8000. Maybe you are trying to use the wrong port?